# How to plot a multiple line plot in Seaborn using specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I have a bigger dataframe that resembles this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'A', '2015': 99, '2016':98, '2017': '95', '2018':'99'}, {'name': 'B', '2015': 76, '2016':89, '2017': 83, '2018': 85}, {'name': 'C', '2015': 88, '2016':89, '2017': 91, '2018':91}])

df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
```

[image]

I would like to plot A, B, and C in a multiline plot for just the years of 2016 and 2018. After searching for a while, I can't seem to figure how to plot specific columns from a dataframe. Is the best practice creating a new one for each plot?

Comment: No, just a copy-paste error while creating an example. Thank you for pointing that out, fixed

Comment: You want years on the x axis?

Comment: Yes, x-axis would be years and y-axis would be values for each 'name' for those years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I assume that the years are strings and the values are integers.

Seaborn expects data in tidy format, so first you might transform your dataframe.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"name": "A", "2015": 99, "2016": 98, "2017": 95, "2018": 99},
        {"name": "B", "2015": 76, "2016": 89, "2017": 83, "2018": 85},
        {"name": "C", "2015": 88, "2016": 89, "2017": 91, "2018": 91},
    ]
)

df.set_index("name", inplace=True)
tidy = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_1": "year", 0: "values"})
```

Here is the outcome

```py
    name    year    values
0   A   2015    99
1   A   2016    98
2   A   2017    95
3   A   2018    99
4   B   2015    76
5   B   2016    89
6   B   2017    83
7   B   2018    85
8   C   2015    88
9   C   2016    89
10  C   2017    91
11  C   2018    91
```

Then, you can

1. filter it for the years you want
2. pass it as a `data` parameter
3. specify the columns at `x`, `y`, and `hue`

```
sns.lineplot(
    data=tidy[tidy["year"].isin(["2016", "2018"])], x="year", y="values", hue="name"
)
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have numeric data on the columns and in the values, you can simply melt you dataframe and call a lineplot.

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.melt(id_vars=['name']), 
             x='variable', y='value', hue='name')
```

[image]